# Any Alternate Way of iPhone ipa Distribution ike Diawi.com ? This website was not working last few of days

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Diawi.com is easiest solution for uploading iPhone ipa file and distribution in development phase , but unfortunately diawi is not available right now for some maintenance issues.

I have to send ipa file to client , Can any one recommend me any other quickest solution which is easy to acquire by client as well

Same as diawi.com method will be preferable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: @avi This is related to ipa distribution issue after development

Comment: The simplest way is to get the client to send you their device UUIDs and then you can send them an ad-hoc build that they can install with iTunes

Comment: Try apple's TestFlight.

Comment: Try https://buildtry.com

Comment: I know this is too late to answer but at least it could be useful to somebody. There is a Mac app available that is introduced by Dropbox. https://www.tryappbox.com. More over the urls generated using this app has no expiry until you delete.

Comment: Yes. I am using https://installonair.com for sending builds to clients. Main benefit of this platform is, they are not deleting builds like diawi does and expire build in just 3 to 4 days. I have one active build since 35 days so it’s plus point.

Comment: Try [AppByAir](https://appbyair.com/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As said by @paulw just simply add UDID of clients device and make ad-hoc build to client. And if you want to know other site like diawi ,

Then check this , it is user-friendly site like diawi ,

[betafamily.com](https://betafamily.com/supersend)

[image]

Or you can also one of the usefulway from below link ,

[4-waysmethods-install-ipa-file-app-iphone-ipad-ipod-online-offline-methods](http://techapple.net/2015/01/4-waysmethods-install-ipa-file-app-iphone-ipad-ipod-online-offline-methods/)

Comment: Welcome @UmairAhmed this link is very easy like diawi. so this is the best option when diawi is in maintainance

Comment: yes mate correct